# Redux ToolKIt Query getState on prepareHeaders show null on getState().auth.accessToken

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Hello everyone so I have problem with my RTK Query where the `prepareHeaders getState()` not getting the value from the auth state. So I have accessToken state in my store where to store the value of the **accessToken** when user successfully login. But for some reason getState just won't get the value eventhought the value is already in store but still showing null in getState(). But if i call the function of login again which will dispatch accessToken value second time then the value will appear in `getState()`. But I don't know why is that happening.
This is my code:

**ApiSlice.js**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { setAccessToken, logOut } from "../slice/authSlice";

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:8000" ,
  credentials: "include",
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      // Get the access token from your store
      const accessToken = getState().auth.accessToken
      console.log(accessToken)
      // console.log('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`)
      // If there is an access token, set the authorization header
      if (accessToken) {
        headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
      }
      return headers;
   }
});
```

**userApiSlice.js**

```
export const userApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) =>({
        userRegister: builder.mutation({
            query: (value) =>({
                url: "/register",
                method: "POST",
                body: value,
            })
        }),
        login : builder.mutation({
            query: (value) => ({
              url : "/login",
              method : "POST",
              body : value,
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ["Users"],
            onQueryStarted: async (value, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) => {
                const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
                const accessToken = data.accessToken
                dispatch(setAccessToken(accessToken));
              },
          }),
    })
});
```

**authSlice.js**

```
const initialState = {
    accessToken: null,
}

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name : "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        setAccessToken: (state, action) =>{
            state.accessToken = action.payload;
        },
        logOut: ()=> initialState
    },
```

})

so if i call the login function here which is the login mutation
**login function**

```
const [loginUser, { isLoading, isError, error}] = useLoginMutation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const loginSubmit = async (value) => {
    const {accessToken} = await loginUser(value).unwrap();
    console.log(accessToken)
    navigate("/");
  };
```

So if I run this loginSubmit first time the accessToken will be store the authSlice.js accessToken but the getState().auth just wont get the value but the second call on the function loginSubmit that will send accessToken to the getState why is that? I just can't find the solution. Can someone help me?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where the problem is in your code, on first glance looks valid. But normally you do that via extra reducer:

```js
const authSlice = createSlice({
  ...
  reducers:{
     ...
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
  builder.addMatcher(
    userApiSlice.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled,
      (state, { payload }) => {
        state.accessToken = payload.accessToken
      }
    )
  },
});
```

idk, that the case, but this won't trigger if you have the response cached already...

Comment: Ok I will try this. Thanks

Comment: it works, Thanks. by adding extrareducers now accessToken got the value in prepareHeaders. But is kind a funny I dont need add extraReducer before on my previous project and it work perfectly. It usually just an alternative adding extraReducer. But for some reason on this project I need to add it to work. dont know why. But thanks again for the help.

Comment: I think extra reducer is more appropriate in that case, there maybe multiple queries that include token (like forgot password result) so there is special kind of matcher isOneOf, that allows to subscribe to multiple   same time